# Handling complex data objects with Reactjs

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

I am trying to create a table of orders. I work with React+Redux.
I have my data stored in props.
The data is structured similar to this: (a bit more detailed)

```
[{ //stored in props(redux state)
      "id": 37, //order 1
      "content": {
        "items": {
          "47427": {
            "price": "12.49",
            "format": "[\"1x12\"]",
            "quantity": 1,
          },
           "23451": {
            "price": "18.99",
            "format": "[\"1x7\"]",
            "quantity": 1,
          },
        }
      },
      "address": {
        "first_name": "Tyrion",
        "last_name": "Lannister",
        "line1": "The Red Keep",
        "city": "King's Landing",
        "country": "Westeros",
      }
    }, {
      "id": 38, //order 2
      "content": {
        "items": {
          "183429": {
            "price": "8.99",
            "format": "[\"1x7\"]",
            "quantity": "1",
          }
        }
      },
      "address": {
        "first_name": "Arya",
        "last_name": "Stark",
        "line1": "23 Wolf st.",
        "city": "Winterfell",
        "country": "Westeros",
      }
    }, {
      "id": 30, //order 3
      "content": {
        "items": {
          "20399": {
            "price": "21.99",
            "format": "[\"1x12\"]",
            "quantity": 1,
          }
        }
      },
      "address": {
        "first_name": "Jon",
        "last_name": "Snow",
        "line1": "29 Winter is here st.",
        "city": "The Wall",
        "country": "Westeros",
      }
    }]
```

I want to access the "content" and "address" properties of each order and display it in a table. So i tried to call orders.map() on this object but this only gives me access to the first layer of properties - for instance order.id.
When i try to access order.content.item.price i get an error "can't read property of undefined".

My question goes on about order.content.items. that's when i have another object to iterate over since it has different property names, that contain properties inside them (.price, .format, .quantity).
So basically, how do i handle this complex data, so I can grab every piece of info in this object and place them in my table?

```
    //my render function of <OrdersTable />
    render() {
        let filter = this.props.filter || {};
        let orders = this.props.orders || []; 
        let content = orders.map(order => {
            return (
                <tr key={order.id}>
                    <td>{order.content}</td>
                </tr>
            )
        })
        let address = orders.map(order => {
            return (
                <tr key={order.id}>
                    <td>{order.address.first_name}</td>
                </tr>
            )
        })
        return (
            <div>
                <button className="filter"
                        onClick={this.props.showContent}>
                    Show Content
                </button>
                <button className="filter"
                        onClick={this.props.showAddress}>
                    Show Address
                </button>
                <table className='orders'>
                    <thead className={filter.showContent?'content': 'content hidden'}>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Items</th>
                            <th>Format</th>
                            <th>Quantity</th>
                            <th>Price</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <thead className={filter.showAddress?'address': 'address hidden'}>
                        <tr>
                            <th>First Name</th>
                            <th>Last Name</th>
                            <th>Country</th>
                            <th>City</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody className={filter.showContent?'content': 'content hidden'}>
                       {content}
                    </tbody>
                    <tbody className={filter.showAddress?'address': 'address hidden'}>
                       {address}
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        )
```

Thank you very much :)

*EDIT*:
So here's what did the trick in my case: (with the help of @TW80000 and @TomDavies)

```
       let content = orders.map(order => {
                const items= Object.keys(order.content.items).map(id => {
                   const item= order.content.items[id];
                   return(
                     <tr key={id}>
                        <td>{id}</td>
                        <td>{item.format}</td>
                        <td>{item.quantity}</td>
                        <td>{item.price}</td>
                     </tr>
                  )
              })
            return items;
        });
        const address = orders.map(order => {
            return (
                <tr key={order.id}>
                    <td>{order.address.first_name}</td>
                    <td>{order.address.last_name}</td>
                    <td>{order.address.country}</td>
                    <td>{order.address.state}</td>
                    <td>{order.address.city}</td>
                    <td>{order.address.line1}</td>
                    <td>{order.address.zip}</td>
                </tr>
            )
        });

...

    <tbody className={filter.showContent?'content': 'content hidden'}>
                       {content}
                    </tbody>
                    <tbody className={filter.showAddress?'address': 'address hidden'}>
                       {address}
                    </tbody>
```

Comment: What is the exact error that you are getting? Also are **47427** and **23451** hardcoded values coz it doesnt look like?

Comment: You say you're trying to access `order.content.item.price`, but what you're passing in is structured more like `order.content.items["183429"].price`? Is that a typo in your example?

Comment: @TomDavies I see what you mean there. In that case, how do I iterate over Items to generate the unique item in each case, and his properties?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are working with complex data, I'd rather separate everything into small subcomponents so it get's easier to use and understand the code later.

```
// Only order details
const OrderRow = (order) => {
  return (
    <tr>
      {
        Object.keys(order.content.items).map((key, index) => {
          const item = order.content.items[key]
          return (
            <td key={index}>{item.price} {item.format} {item.quantity}</td>
          )
        })
      }
    </tr>
  )
}

// Only address details 
const AddressRow = (address) => {
  return (
    <tr>
      <td>{adress.first_name}</td>
    </tr>
  )
}


// In your main component, render them all 
render() {
  ...

  return (
    <table>
      ...
      <tbody>
        {orders.map(order => <OrderRow key={order.id} order={order} />)}
      </tbody>
      <tbody>
        {orders.map(order => <AddressRow key={order.id} address={order.address} />)}
      </tbody>
    </table>
  )
}
```

Comment: The separation of the components can be a good idea. although it has nothing to do with solving my problem, thanks.
About your method, Object.keys will return an array of the indexes as strings. Not giving me any access to the data inside them.

Comment: Object.keys will return item ids so you can use to actually get the correspondent item (just like to solution you have chosen) :)

Comment: Yes! I have noticed it right after I solved it, apologies for my misunderstanding ;)

Answer (score 0):

> I want to access the "content" and "adress" properties of each order and display it in a table.

You've spelled address wrong pretty much everywhere, that could be why it's not being read correctly.

> So i tried to call orders.map() on this object but this only gives me access to the first layer of properties - for instance order.id.

That's not true, you will have access to all properties: `id`, `address`, and `content`.

> When i try to access order.content.item.price i get an error "can't read property of undefined".

That's because it's `content.items` with an "s", not `content.item` like you have written. `content.item` is undefined and that's why you get this error.

> My question goes on about order.content.items. that's when i have another object to iterate over since it has different property names, that contain properties inside them (.price, .format, .quantity).

You can do a nested loop. Example:

```
let content = orders.map(order => {
  const tds = Object.keys(order.content.items).map(id => {
    const item = order.content.items[id];
    // You can use item.quality and item.format here as well
    return(<td>{item.price}</td>);
  })
  return (
    <tr key={order.id}>{tds}</tr>
  );
})
```

Comment: Haha, It's extremely ridiculous of me, but I really have mistaken "adress" all over my example.
About items, its not really the case. The example is different from the real data. items represents something else in the original code.
The nested loop - 
when i try that i get "Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): order.content.items.map is not a function".
So i am still left with that question.

Comment: Yeah, you can't call `.map()` on `items` in your example because it's an object and not an array, you could use TW80000's example if you map on `Object.keys(order.content.items)` or something instead though. That will give you an array of the item ids, see: [Object.keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys).

Comment: @Amiry My mistake, I forgot that `items` is an object, not an array. Like @Tom Davies mentioned, you can use `Object.keys` to easily fix this. I've updated my answer. Try that.

Comment: I tried that. {item.price} returns undefined. Object.keys(order.content.items) will return 3 arrays of strings, for example: ["47427", "23451"]
No further values can be reached by this method.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to update the function body. I updated my answer again. Give it another try.

Comment: Glad you got it. Feel free to mark this answer as accepted so it doesn't show up in the unanswered queue.